# How to list all composer modules and GitHub URLs installed in a Laravel project?

Tags: php, composer-php

I was building sort of an analytics software.

How can I find the Github Urls of installed composer/PHP modules in a Laravel project?

I'd like to see all of those URLs not like by one, but as a whole something like a list probably in the console.

Something like this:

```
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/twigphp/Twig" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/sitepoint/Rauth" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/PHP-DI/PHP-DI" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/Respect/Validation" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/doctrine/annotations" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/thephpleague/glide" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/tamtamchik/simple-flash" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/cakephp/orm" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/Bee-Lab/bowerphp" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/markstory/mini-asset" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/natxet/CssMin" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/linkorb/jsmin-php" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/consolidation-org/Robo" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper" },
{ "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/consolidation-org/Robo" },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`composer info` won't give you that information.

The easiest way would be to get it from `composer.lock` directly. Instead of writing your own parser, you could use a ready-made tool like [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

After downloading it you could write an expression like this one:

```sh
jq -c ".packages[]|{url:.source.url, type: .source.type}" composer.lock
```

This would filter the `packages` property of `composer.lock`, and will create an output very similar to the one you want. E.g.:

```
{"url":"https://github.com/api-platform/api-pack.git","type":"git"}
{"url":"https://github.com/api-platform/core.git","type":"git"}
{"url":"https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php.git","type":"git"}
{"url":"https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony.git","type":"git"}
{"url":"https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions.git","type":"git"}
```

This other expression would create an array of objects, already comma separated as in your example (but less compact):

```
jq "[.packages[]|{url:.source.url, type: .source.type}]" composer.lock
```

Results:

```
[
  {
    "url": "https://github.com/api-platform/api-pack.git",
    "type": "git"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://github.com/api-platform/core.git",
    "type": "git"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php.git",
    "type": "git"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-symfony.git",
    "type": "git"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions.git",
    "type": "git"
  }
[...]
]
```

Comment: no the most important thing there is that I'd get the urls of the modules not like the `type` entry

Comment: I don't understand, the URLs of the modules are included in all the outputs on this answer.